How to save the best model after running hyperparameter_search with Hugging Face Transformers?
I'm currently doing hyperparameter tuning by using the 'hyperparameter_search' function from the Transformers library. However, the process run completely, but I'm curious on how can I save the best model from the 'hyperparameter_search' function? It seems like there is less discussion on this topic.
The code provided below is not the complete version, but it's enough for understanding on my flow.
def training_args():
  return TrainingArguments(output_dir=model_name,
                           overwrite_output_dir=True,
                           num_train_epochs=2,
                           learning_rate=2e-5,
                           per_device_train_batch_size=batch_size,
                           per_device_eval_batch_size=batch_size,
                           weight_decay=0.01,
                           eval_strategy="epoch",
                           push_to_hub=False,
                           log_level="error",
                           max_steps=-1)

def trainer_hyperparam():
  return Trainer(
      model_init=model_init,
      args=training_args(),
      compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
      train_dataset=encoded_dataset['train'],
      eval_dataset=encoded_dataset['validation'],
      tokenizer=tokenizer
  )

trainer = trainer_hyperparam()

trainer.hyperparameter_search(
    hp_space=lambda _: config,
    backend='ray',
    n_trials=1,
    resources_per_trial={
        "cpu": 1,
        "gpu": 1
    },
    scheduler=scheduler,
    keep_checkpoints_num=1,
    checkpoint_score_attr="training_iteration",
    stop=None,
    progress_reporter=reporter,
    storage_path="~/ray_results/",
    name="tune_transformer_pbt"
)

I have tried using 'trainer.save_model()' but result with this error "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'state_dict'"

I have found a solution for this question as follow:
best_run = trainer.hyperparameter_search(
  hp_space=lambda _: config,
  backend='ray',
  n_trials=1,
  resources_per_trial={
    "cpu": 1,
    "gpu": 1
  },
  scheduler=scheduler,
  keep_checkpoints_num=1,
  checkpoint_score_attr="training_iteration",
  stop=None,
  progress_reporter=reporter,
  storage_path="~/ray_results/",
  name="tune_transformer_pbt"
)

for n, v in best_run.hyperparameters.items():
  setattr(trainer.args, n, v)

trainer.train()

trainer.save_model("/your_path_here")

